# Call facebook api with only a user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm working on a social alarm clock, that lets you login on facebook through a smartphone application. Next thing to do is show your facebook feed on a seperate website. So when I store the user access token on login, would I be able to fetch data from facebook api with only the access token, without the user logged in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of can perform activities on behalf of user if you have an active user's access token.

But this token will expire soon. So may be you can extend this token on the server side, then it will have the expiration of 60 days. But before it expires make sure you refresh the token else it become invalidate again.

Read this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) to know more about access tokens and its extension.

Comment: Then how should I make an API call using the Graph API? Don't seem to get it working without being logged in? Thanks for you help!

Comment: Since you are storing the token, you can use that to make the calls, eg: `/me/feed?access_token={saved-token}`. Hope you got it now.

Comment: When I use 'me' or another user ID, then this user is logged in, right? I have to retrieve data from a user, while he is not logged in.

Comment: No, its not necessary. Its just everything about access token. If you have the valid user access token, you can even perfom `/me` calls using the access token: `/me?fields=access_token` and API call will give you the details of the users- no login , nothing is required. That's what I've explained in teh answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution! When a user logs in, I recieve a short-live token, I then make an ajax call to a php file, which gets me a long-live token by using

```
  $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Next i'm storing the $accessToken (this is the long-live one) in the database. Then on my alarmclock (just another website) I fetch the token from the database (ajax) and I can start making API calls on behalf of the user, without him being logged in!

Hope I also helped other people with this! If you have any questions, just aske me, i'm kinda getting good at this :)!

Thanks for your help!

Cheers